# Android Emulator Keyboard not displaying but responding to taps

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I'm working in Android Studio and I completed an error less code for a simple tip calculator app but when I launch it in the emulator and click on the Text Fields, the UI shifts up but the numeric keypad doesn't appear.

It responds how it should when I tap where the numbers should be but it just doesn't show?

[image]

This is the code that has anything to do with keyboard:

```
 EditNumberField(
        value = amountInput,
        label = R.string.bill_amount,
        keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions.Default.copy(
            keyboardType = KeyboardType.Number,
            imeAction = ImeAction.Next),
        onValueChanged = { amountInput = it },
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(bottom = 32.dp)
            .fillMaxWidth()
    )

    EditNumberField(
        label = R.string.how_was_the_service,
        keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions.Default.copy(
            keyboardType = KeyboardType.Number,
            imeAction = ImeAction.Done),
        value = tipInput,
        onValueChanged = {tipInput = it},
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(bottom = 32.dp)
            .fillMaxWidth())

    Text(
        text = stringResource(R.string.tip_amount, tip),
        style = MaterialTheme.typography.displaySmall
    )
    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(150.dp))
}
```

}

```
@Composable
fun EditNumberField(
    @StringRes label: Int,
    keyboardOptions: KeyboardOptions,
    value: String,
    onValueChanged: (String) -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {

TextField(
    value = value,
    onValueChange = onValueChanged,
    singleLine = true,
    modifier = modifier,
    label = { Text(stringResource(label)) },
    keyboardOptions = keyboardOptions
)
```

}

Comment: Can you add a screenshot?

Comment: I did now, the UI shifts up and I entered number 8 by guessing where it would be on the keyboard, but, the keyboard is not there???

Comment: Does this problem occur only in your app or in all apps?

Comment: The keyboard worked before, and on other apps. I can add the code to see if I overlooked something in there if you think it'll help?

Answer (score 1):

It was an emulator issue, solved with a simple restart! First rule of IT, guys, don't be me.